# If a function is undefined at a point will its integral be defined at that point?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

In case of differentiation, if function is undefined, it is also undifferentiable at that point. But I was wondering if the same applies in the case of integrals also?

Comment: A very similar question was asked recently. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496865/computing-an-integral-when-the-function-is-not-defined-at-some-point

Comment: Which integrals? I presume your talking about indefinite integrals. Reading the definition of an indefinite integral, or of an antiderivative, would answer your question completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a function must be defined to be integrable (the integral wouldn't make sense otherwise).

However you can define a point however you like and it doesn't affect the integrability (single points do not affect integrability).

So if you're thinking of something like $f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-2}$ on the interval $[1,3]$ then strictly speaking $f(x)$ is not integrable there because $f(2)$ isn't in the domain. However, you can define:

$$\hat{f}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)\text{ for } x\neq 2\\\text{anything for } x=2\end{cases}$$

and $\hat f$ is integrable on $[1,3]$.

Answer (score 1):

no, $\int \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{x}+C$ $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is not defined at $0$, but $\sqrt{x}$ is.

Comment: $1/\sqrt{x}$ is not integrable on any neighborhood of $0$ because it is unbounded.

Comment: It is integrable as you can see from my first comment.

Comment: No, a function is (Riemann) integrable iff it is bounded and its discontinuity set has Lebesgue measure 0. Your function is not integrable on any neighborhood of 0 because its unbounded. The improper Riemann integral exists though.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of an indefinite integral of a function $\int f(x)dx$ is defined solely for functions whose domain is a set $A$ which is a union of intervals and we consider the integral for each of these intervals separately.

But for the sake of simplifying things we write $I= \int f(x)dx$ and imply that we refer only to the intervals where $f$ is defined.